# Swagger Auto Gen with custom routing

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

So I am trying to generate a basic documentation for my routing now the routes are not your normal expressjs routes like `router.get` etc.

My issue is the swagger autogen is not seeing any routes and not making anything on it.

Here is a sample for them

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const isAuthenticated = require('../../middlewares/authMiddleware')
const isAdmin = require('../../middlewares/isAdmin')
const { hasPermission } = require('../../controllers/permissions')

const router = express.Router()

/**
 * The function recursively loads routes from a directory and adds them to a router object.
 * @param directory - The directory path where the routes are located.
 * @param [currentPath] - The current path is a string representing the current directory path being
 * traversed by the function. It is used to construct the endpoint URL for each route based on the
 * directory structure. If not provided, it defaults to an empty string.
 */
function loadRoutes(directory, currentPath = '') {
    fs.readdirSync(directory, { withFileTypes: true }).forEach((dirent) => {
        const fullPath = path.join(directory, dirent.name)
        if (dirent.isDirectory()) {
            loadRoutes(fullPath, path.join(currentPath, dirent.name))
        } else if (dirent.isFile() && !(currentPath === '' && dirent.name === 'index.js')) {
            const route = require(fullPath)
            console.log(`Loading route: ${route.metadata.method} ${path.join(currentPath, path.parse(dirent.name).name)}`)
            const endpoint = route.metadata.url || path.join(currentPath, path.parse(dirent.name).name)
            const middlewares = route.metadata?.middlewares || []
            if (route.metadata.requiresAuth) {
                if (router[route.metadata.method.toLowerCase()]) {
                    router[route.metadata.method.toLowerCase()](endpoint, isAuthenticated, ...middlewares, route.handler)
                }
            } else if (route.metadata.requiresPermission && route.metadata.requiresAuth) {
                if (hasPermission(route.metadata.permissions)) {
                    if (router[route.metadata.method.toLowerCase()]) {
                        router[route.metadata.method.toLowerCase()](endpoint, isAuthenticated, isAdmin, ...middlewares, route.handler)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (router[route.metadata.method.toLowerCase()]) {
                    router[route.metadata.method.toLowerCase()](endpoint, ...middlewares, route.handler)
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

loadRoutes(__dirname)

module.exports = router
```

This is my handler which loads in the routes that are in multiple sub-sub folders for organizing the routes and here is a sample route

```
const { PERMISSIONS_MAP } = require('../../../controllers/permissions')
const responseHandler = require('../../../modules/responseHandler')

const database = require('../../../config/database')

const {
    Products,
} = database.models

module.exports = {
    metadata: {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/products/get',
        version: '1.0.0',
        requiresAuth: false,
        permissions: [],
        requiresPermission: false,
        middlewares: []
    },
    handler: async (req, res, next) => {
        responseHandler(req, res, 200, { products: [] }, null, 'Products retrieved successfully')
    }
}
```

And here is my swagger gen script **Yes it is copied from the documentation**

```
const swaggerAutogen = require('swagger-autogen')()


const doc = {
    info: {
        version: "1.0.0",
        title: "My API",
        description: "Documentation automatically generated by the <b>swagger-autogen</b> module."
    },
    host: "localhost:3000",
    basePath: "/",
    schemes: ['http', 'https'],
    consumes: ['application/json'],
    produces: ['application/json'],
    tags: [
        {
            "name": "User",
            "description": "Endpoints"
        }
    ],
    securityDefinitions: {
        apiKeyAuth: {
            type: "apiKey",
            in: "header",       // can be "header", "query" or "cookie"
            name: "X-API-KEY",  // name of the header, query parameter or cookie
            description: "any description..."
        }
    },
    definitions: {
        Parents: {
            father: "Simon Doe",
            mother: "Marie Doe"
        },
        User: {
            name: "Jhon Doe",
            age: 29,
            parents: {
                $ref: '#/definitions/Parents'
            },
            diplomas: [
                {
                    school: "XYZ University",
                    year: 2020,
                    completed: true,
                    internship: {
                        hours: 290,
                        location: "XYZ Company"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        AddUser: {
            $name: "Jhon Doe",
            $age: 29,
            about: ""
        }
    }
}

const outputFile = './swagger-output.json'
const endpointsFiles = ['./src/routes/v1/index.js']

swaggerAutogen(outputFile, endpointsFiles, doc).then(() => {
    require('./app.js')           // Your project's root file
})
```

Comment: So, what is the problem here? You've not asked a question.

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question. My issue is the swagger autogen is not seeing any routes and not making anything on it.

Comment: What is ./src/routes/v1/index.js?